# Setting dimensions for video attachment for Timeline item

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Mirror API allows you to insert a timeline item with a video attachment. Is there a way to set the dimensions of the video so that it doesn't look stretched out for non 16:9 videos?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the current version of the API and Glass client, the best solution is to make sure that your videos are within this aspect ratio for now.

However, please file a feature request in our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) as I'm sure other developers would be interested in such a feature.